# SQL Server Select Duplicate Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following structure:

```
TABLE1         TABLE2
id_worker_main  id_worker
id_worker_sub   name_worker
```

I need to make a select getting the name_worker for both id_worker_main and id_worker_sub, but I can't. The following query return the same name twice.

```
SELECT t2.name_worker as main, t2.name_worker as sub 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON t1.id_worker_main = t2.id_worker AND t1.id_worker_sub = t2.id_worker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join with the same table twice. Just use a different alias for each join

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38539/1)**

With this workers

```
INSERT INTO Table2
    ([id_worker], [name_worker])
VALUES
    (1, 'Juan'),
    (2, 'Angela'),
    (3, 'Peter');
```

And this relationship

```
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([id_worker_main], [id_worker_sub])
VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (1, 3);
```

Use this query

```
SELECT A.name_worker MAINWORKER, B.name_worker SUBWORKER
FROM Table1 T1 
Inner join Table2 A
   ON T1.id_worker_main = A.id_worker
Inner join Table2 B
   ON T1.id_worker_sub = B.id_worker
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| MAINWORKER | SUBWORKER |
|------------|-----------|
|       Juan |    Angela |
|     Angela |     Peter |
|       Juan |     Peter |
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you can join table2 multiple times

```
SELECT t21.name_worker as main, t22.name_worker as sub
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t21 on t21.id_worker = t1.id_worker_main
JOIN table2 t22 on t22.id_worker = t1.id_worker_sub
```